# Inversion of inheritance in WPF styles

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got a UserControl that contains a button:

```
<Button Content="Button"/>
```

And a style:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
</Style>
```

The parent window (or another UserControl) may set another more general style:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
</Style>
```

The result is (what is obvious) that parent buttons will have more general style (Red) and my user control will have buttons with more specific style (Blue).

---

I'm wondering how to invert such behaviour in order to achieve something like setting the default style in my custom user control which could be then overriden in parent control or window if necessary?

The key is, that **default style** is defined first in custom user control and it is **overriden** automaticly by its parent. That is way I called it an inversion.

---

The imaginary example of the solution maight look like the following:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" StylePriority="Default">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
</Style>
```

The `StylePriority` could indicate that if there is no other style defined for that button, then the default style should be applied to it.

Comment: if you want to use the default style in parent control, why bother defining another style again in your `usercontrol`?

Comment: @Bolu: Edited to better understanding. I want to define default style in user control but then I would like to be able to override it in parent window. Let's say: blue button as defult defined in custom control. Override that in parent window in order to get red button.

Comment: i'm not 100% sure but i don't think there is a easy way to do what you wan't  it's like inversing the VisualTree :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use dynamic resources.

A UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Example.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Example">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="local:UserControl1">
            <Style.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="UserControl1.DefaultButtonStyle">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </Style>
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Button Content="UserControlButton" Style="{DynamicResource UserControl1.DefaultButtonStyle}"/>
</UserControl>
```

And a Window:

```
<Window x:Class="Example.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Example">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <local:UserControl1 >
            <local:UserControl1.Resources>
                <Style x:Key="UserControl1.DefaultButtonStyle" TargetType="Button"
                    BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="40" />
                </Style>
            </local:UserControl1.Resources>
        </local:UserControl1>
        <Button Content="WindowButton" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

If you remove the style for the control in the window, the default user control button style will be applied.

Answer (score 1):

Create a dependency property in your `UserControl` for the buttons colour, and then bind to it. You can specify a default value of blue for that property.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonColorProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonColor", typeof(Color), typeof(MyUserControl),
    new PropertyMetadata(Colors.Blue));

public Color State
{
    get { return (Color)this.GetValue(ButtonColorProperty); }
    set { this.SetValue(ButtonColorProperty, value); } 
}

<UserControl ...
             x:Name="root">
    <Button Content="Button" Background="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=ButtonColor}" />
</UserControl>
```

Then set that property to red where you want to use the `UserControl`.

```
<local:MyUserControl ButtonColor="Red" />
```